# jQuery dataTables add id to added row

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to add ID to last added row with jQuery DataTables (e.g., `<tr id="myid">...</tr>`) ?

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        "col_value_1",
        "col_value_2",
        "col_value_3",
        "col_value_4" ] );
```

(Add id to this new row)

Comment: Do the other table rows have ids?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the **[fnCreatedRow/createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow)** Callback. It is best to set the id attribute of the table row on creation of the row. Use what the API has provided and you won't need to hack it or have messy code

> This function is called when a TR element is created (and all TD child elements have been inserted), or registered if using a DOM source, allowing manipulation of the TR element (adding classes etc).

```
//initialiase dataTable and set config options
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    ....
    'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'my' + iDataIndex); // or whatever you choose to set as the id
    },
    ....
});

// add data to table post-initialisation
table.fnAddData([
    'col_value_1',
    'col_value_2',
    'col_value_3',
    'col_value_4'
]);
```

Comment: You'd think there was an easier way to do this when adding a row. I'm using an authenticated, serialized, heavily processed API to fetch data, so I have to use server-supplied IDs within child elements of tds and then use that event callback to transfer from the child to the row. This is a completely back-assward way to have to do this.

Comment: I agree. Seriously, you can't supply an ID to a row? This is like very basic functionality. How else would you edit/remove existing rows if you couldn't target them by IDs? Sure, they automatically get IDs, but how often is it that you want to use your own IDs because the application is already built?

Comment: The callback link is broken. Currently it is found under [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow). `fnCreatedRow` still works as well.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a more cleaner approach that I found [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38483/how-do-you-add-an-id-to-a-new-row-using-t-row-add):

```
table.row.add( [ ... ] ).node().id = 'myId';
table.draw( false );
```

Comment: great, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: This is the correct answer for later versions of the jquery DataTable.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
var MyUniqueID = "tr123"; // this is the uniqueId.
var rowIndex = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([ "column1Data", "column2Data"]);
var row = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
$(row).attr('id', MyUniqueID);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use row.add() it is easy to set the id:

```
   var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   var rowNode = table.row.add([
        "col_value_1",
        "col_value_2",
        "col_value_3",
        "col_value_4"
    ]).node();

    $(rowNode).attr("id", myid);
```

The .node() returns the  element of the newly added row.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```html
var rowNode=$('#MyTable').DataTable().row.add([1,2,3]).draw( false );

rowNode.id='myId';
```

rowNode.id='myId';

Answer (score -1):

Hope below code will help you

```
var rowid = $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    "col_value_1",
    "col_value_2",
    "col_value_3",
    "col_value_4" ] );
var theNode = $('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[rowid[0]].nTr;
theNode.setAttribute('id','your value');
```