# How to generate jQuery DataTables rowId client side?

Tags: datatables, rowid

The jQuery DataTables [reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId) shows an example of setting the `rowId` option to a column from the data source (server side). This setting is used for the "select" extension and [retaining row selection on Ajax reload](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/reload.html).

Is there any way to generate the row identifier value 1) client side, or 2) as a combination of multiple columns from the data source?

Example data source:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "aid": 5421,
        "bid": 4502,
        "name": "John Smith"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$("#datatable").DataTable({
    select: true,
    //rowId: "aid" each row ID is the value of the "aid" column
    //       e.g., <tr id="5421">

    //rowId: 0 each row ID is the value of the 0-indexed column
    //       e.g., <tr id="5421"> (same as above)

    rowId: [0, 1] // How? row ID combined value of 2+ columns
                  // e.g. <tr id="5421-4502">

    rowId: "random" // How? random generated client-side ID
                    // e.g., <tr id="id34e04">
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to do this directly. As a workaround, you could use the [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId) option and/or the [`rowId`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId) option:

```
// Example using dataSrc option to manipulate data:
$("#example").dataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "data.json",
        dataSrc: function (json) {
            for (var i = 0, ien = json.data.length; i < ien; i++) {
                json.data[i][0] = '<a href="' + json.data[i][0] + '">View Message</a>';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#datatable").DataTable({
    ...
    'createdRow': function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'row' + iDataIndex); // or if you prefer 'row' + aData.aid + aData.bid
    },   
    ...
});
```

I updated it from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114936/1827854) that seems to be a duplicate of this one. The `createdRow` callback is [documented here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow).