# Dynamically add id to datatable row based on AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have seen posts on giving arbituary ids to datatable rows using row callback [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html). I want to give rows specific ids based on my AJAX response `dataToUse`; each row will have a unique id given as one field of a JSON object. Here's the structure of my datatable:

```
table = $('#_table').dataTable({
                ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                    $.ajax({
                             type: "post",
                             url: '/test/getvalues',
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (result) {
                                var dataToUse = {};
                                dataToUse.data = result.map.count;
                                callback(dataToUse);
                             }
                           });
                  }
        })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to perform some operation on particular rows based on the information you get from dataToUse? To begin, I'll describe the behavior that is happening in the example you provide. The code reads:

```
if ( data[5].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 > 150000 ) {
    $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
}
```

Which is checking to see if the 6th item in data, the salary, is greater than 150,000, and if it is, selecting that item using a CSS selector through jQuery and then is adding a class to it.

Based on your question, you want to perform a similar table-modifying behavior based on some data provided by result to dataToUse. In that case, result will need to provide some sort of information that allows you to construct an appropriate jQuery selector, $(someSelector) to choose the rows you want to modify, and then you can modify them as needed. You can perform all this in your success function.

I would suggest updating their classes rather than ids if you want to add some specific styling or behavior to them. Updating the id tends to be bad practice.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I ran into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114555/jquery-datatables-add-id-to-added-row and it seems that using 'fnCreatedRow' function, I will be able to access each row and give it an ID. I wanted to give every row an ID. Say my success function will get a result object of [ "id"  : "1234", "name": "wendy", "count" : "3"]. I'd like to grab that ID and give it to the row where the name is wendy and count is 3 in my datatable.

Answer (score 0):

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114555/jquery-datatables-add-id-to-added-row), whose answer has been pasted here, gives the answer,

```
    'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'my' + iDataIndex); // or whatever you choose to set as the id
    },
```

`aData` somehow is the AJAX data that I received. This is like magic to me but it worked!